# Passing user control properties from controller to view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, properties, setting

I have created a layout page which has some regularly used user controls (like buttons, text box etc). But the visibility of these controls are determined by the view which is defined from this layout page. What is the best way of setting these values of the view in MVC3? can I pass the property values from the controller to the view?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
--Kuppa

Comment: Could you please explain a little more what exactly do you mean by `user controls` as this notion worries me when used in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag should be able to help you out http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx